# How to set ace-editor content when container block is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I am trying to set ace editor content when container block is hidden.

I am not able to to the same.

Here is what i am trying 
http://jsfiddle.net/U5JtP/408/

Here is my code :

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('.panel-body').hide();
    $('#hide').hide();
    $('#Show').hide();
    $('#setValue').show();
});

$('#Show').click(function(){
    $('.panel-body').show();
    $('#setValue').hide();
    $('#Show').hide();
    $('#hide').show();
});

$('#setValue').click(function(){
    editor.getSession().setValue('function foo(items) {}');
    $('.panel-body').hide();
    $('#setValue').hide();
    $('#Show').show();
    $('#hide').hide();
});

////// -------------------------- Click on Hide -> SetValue -> Show
/// Why ace editor did not updated the content and how to update in such scenario?
```

Can you make that work?

Answer (score 2):

The value is being set, but the editor is not being updated. So you have to call it manually using [`updateFull()` which is a method of ace editor's VirtualRenderer](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=virtual_renderer).

This is how the method can be called

```
editor.renderer.updateFull();
```

Update the setValue method to something like this

```
$('#setValue').click(function(){
    editor.getSession().setValue('function foo(items) {}');
    editor.renderer.updateFull();
    $('.panel-body').hide();
    $('#setValue').hide();
    $('#Show').show();
    $('#hide').hide();
});
```

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/U5JtP/410/** ;

PS: I notice a small delay in updating the editor if updateFull is used in `#setValue` click handler. If updateFull is used in `#show` click handler there is not delay.

Comment: i do consider your answer, but i am seeking a better answer. which would do some internal configuration in ace. That i don't want have to call `updateFull` manually.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. You should just set a new value and updateFull() after you display the editor block. Then it will work properly. I had same issue but I tried this way. It works now

```js
$('#setValue').click(function(){
    $('.panel-body').hide();
    $('#setValue').hide();
    $('#Show').show();
    $('#hide').hide();
    editor.getSession().setValue('function foo(items) {}');
    editor.renderer.updateFull();
});
```